# Windows Deny Create Folder permission not honored by Git Bash

Tags: windows, security, permissions, git-bash

I have a folder on my Windows 7 system. Through the usual Properties->Security->Advanced dialog, I've granted `Deny` for `Create Folders / Append Data` to my current user on this folder. As expected, I can't create a new folder within this folder through File Explorer. Neither can I create a folder using `mkdir` from a Windows Command Prompt.

However, if I launch Git Bash, I can use it's `mkdir` builtin to create a new folder inside the folder. Running `whoami` inside the Git Bash command window returns my user name as expected (albeit in lower case).

Possibly related: while in the directory with the Windows Deny permission set, when I run a `ls -la`, I see that the permissions on the directory are `drwxr-xr-x`. If I run `chmod o-w .` or `chmod o-x .` on from this directory, the directory settings are *unchanged*.

What's going on here? How do I get Git Bash to obey the Windows security permissions?

Comment: `rmdir` also experiences the same behaviour, even if I `Deny Modify`.

Comment: "Git Bash to obey the Windows security permissions?" - It does not.  Windows 10 Linux Subsystem Bash capability will respect it though.

Comment: @Ramhound: so you can violate all filesystem security in Windows just by using Git Bash? That seems problematic.